# Babel Type for 'module.exports'

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-loader

Im writing a function that uses `babel.transform` to detect exported modules such as default & named exports.

For the default and named exports I am using the following babel types for detection:

- `ExportDefaultDeclaration`
- `ExportNamedDeclaration`

But I want to support `module.exports` which is not detected by either type specified above.

I have tried the `DeclareModuleExports` type with no luck.

Anyone have any idea of what type I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no AST type for this. A good tool for exploring things like this is ASTExplorer. Here is an example for your code: http://astexplorer.net/#/gist/46c661d47a6e789437d197ba8d7b1ca8/559ef96e774151f76e2b0e7ff36dc9685d574939

You would have to detect arbitrary accesses to a variable named `module`, and then look for properties named `exports`. In a Babel plugin for instance you could have a visitor that looked for

```
MemberExpression(path) {
  if (
   path.get("object").isIdentifier({name: "module"}) &&
   path.get("property").isIdentifier({name: "exports"})
  ) {
    // whatever
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I will be using the ASTExplorer a lot more now!